# JavaScript call variable as Object and Function like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm trying to create a library for mobile and I want to be able to call the object as function and object like jquery does.

Example:

```
var test = function(elm) {

    this.ajax = function(opt) { ... }
    if ( elm ) {
       var elms = document.querySelectorAll(elm);
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to call it like this:

```
test("#id");
```

and like this:

```
test.ajax(opts);
```

LE:
**Thank you guys for your fast responses!**

Comment: use jquery-mobile instead

Comment: Your use case is not detailed enough. Are you trying to make `test` function like the `jQuery`/`$` object, so that `test('#id')` returns an instance of an object that has a function "method" `.ajax()` available on it?

Comment: jQuery creates a new object (`$`) as soon as the DOM is loaded and attaches methods to it.  It then uses method chaining by returning `this`.  I would check that out instead.

Comment: Although not very difficult problem for me, +1 for asking a question about pure Javascript and trying to learn how things work instead of using existing solutions without knowing what's 'under the hood'. Keep up ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, a function is actually just an object with code attached.

So instead of a plain object:

```
var test = {};
test.ajax = function() { /* ajax */ };
```

... use a function:

```
var test = function() { /* test */ };
test.ajax = function() { /* ajax */ };
```

In both cases, you can access `test.ajax`. The extra thing with the function is that you can call `test`.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question.

Comment: @ErikE I think this is exactly the answer OP's looking for.

Comment: @ErikE: Could you elaborate please? It answers how to create `test` such that you can use it in both ways the OP wants.

Comment: The OP's question already has the pattern you're suggesting. `test` is a function to which a public method is added (albeit inside at execution time as opposed to outside at initial code-loading time). How is your answer really any different? You haven't answered how running a function repeatedly is going to return different instances of that function that all have the same function method available to them.

Comment: @ErikE: No, in the OP's case `ajax` is **not** added to `test` itself. `ajax` should be a "static" function that doesn't have much to do with instances. The OP doesn't want `new test().ajax` or something, but `test.ajax` - so it's a function on the function, not on instances.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was definitely thinking in terms of `new`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ErikE: No problem, glad you understand :)

Comment: And +1 since you are absolutely right. To have a single object that works the way the OP wants, just move the `ajax` function addition to be outside the `test` invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Or mabye something like this:

```
Object.prototype.Test = function( method ) {
    var method = method || null;
    var elms   = null;

    /* Methods */
    this.ajax = function(opt){
        console.log('You called ajax method with options:');
        console.log(opt);
    }
    /* Logic */
    if (method in this) this[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    else {
        try {
            elms = document.querySelectorAll(method);
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }

}
window.onload = function() {
    Test('ajax', {'url':'testurl.com'});
    Test('#aid');  
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend setting `Object.prototype.Test` to create a global `Test` variable. Just use `var Test = ...`.

Comment: Ofcource in many cases it would be better to use var Test = new function( method ) ...
This way he can even use call like Test.ajax( options );
But this is only direction for a way :-)